# How do we make systemManager listen to TitleWindows Move event

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I was trying to find a generic solution to a problem where I was restricting the movement of Popup so that it does not go off the Application Screen , I just wanted to make sure that I listen to the move events of Popup so that these events can be heard in SysmtemManager and get the rawchildren where we have the popup and check for conditionts to make sure that they dont go off the screen in that way I dont need to write the code for everypop move event to restrict .

Can somebody share your experience if  you have done before listening to the move events of PopUp.

Thanks
Sid

Answer (score 0):

On mouseDown, you can check if the header is being clicked, if true then you can use the piece of code below to start a drag operation confined to the application:

```
titleWindow.startDrag(false, new Rectangle(0, 0, Application.height, Application.width))
```

On mouseUp you need to call the following method:

```
titleWindow.stopDrag()
```